# QGIS missing documentation about GetFeatureInfo result template

Tags: qgis, wms, getfeatureinfo, documentation

How/where to change HTML of GetFeatureInfo result?

GeoServer's documentation has [GetFeatureInfo Templates](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html) about changing GetFeatureInfo result template.

ArcGIS's documentation has [Customizing a WMS GetFeatureInfo response](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/customizing-a-wms-getfeatureinfo-response.htm) about changing GetFeatureInfo result template.

Could not find appropiate information in QGIS documentation. Found someting about "writing a filter" in this [page](https://www.itopen.it/qgis-server-getfeatureinfo-with-style/). It is mentioned here that `Currently, the HTML response template is hardcoded and there is no way to customize it` and [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/services.html?highlight=getfeatureinfo#qgisserver-wmts-getfeatureinfo) I did not see any mentions about GetFeatureInfo response template

For example, I want to remove first - layer name - row from the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the field that may appear in the GetFeatureInfo response in WMS.

You go in the Layer propriety, then in "Fields" tab. Here you have the two column WMS and WFS that you may check or uncheck to show them or not.

This answer to the example you want to solve, at least for my understanding.

Comment: Yes, this would solve the example problem but not main issue